what kind of material to resurface exterior concrete foundation
basic gray concrete foundation, of houses in northeast US 50+ years old, what kind of plaster or cement or whatever would you use to fill in the exterior surface prior to painting where the smooth finish has eroded up to an inch to where you see the aggregate of the concrete?  Such that simply painting it would not look good, it needs to be patched first.

You have been around for more than eight years. You should know by now that product-recommendation questions are specifically forbidden on almost all SE sites.

Rephrased from request for specific produce to request for kind(s) of product(s), voted to reopen.

oh I think u know what I meant.  U saying i was looking for a [specifc] product recommendation was a gross misinterpretation and an excuse to close the question.  I specifically said what kind of plaster or cement or whatever to patch.  I did not ask for what specific brand to buy.   I think I will use your justification on 90% of the posts here to close questions.

I don't even remember what I originally said since it was editted

one thing I did learn from here after 8 years is how to recognize an authority complex
